# A minimalistic human-readable serialisation format parser for an embedded system

Tags: c, serialization, embedded, yaml, human-readable

By *"human-readable serialisation format"* I mean `YAML`, `JSON`, `INI` or like. Please note, `XML` is too verbose and too inconvenient for my purposes, so let's leave it alone as the last resort.

The format should store the data as *"named key -- value"* pairs and allow for nesting and arrays. Absence of arrays is not critical, though. Also, type-awareness (ability to return data not only as plain strings) is highly appreciated.

What I need exactly is a pure **C** library, which provides an API for parsing data (encoding is optional and of lesser importance). It must fit into somewhat about 16-20 KiB, when compiled for ARM7.

I've googled and wikied around, but couldn't find an artifact satisfying all the above requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) a while back and it might fit your requirements.

Comment: Though I've finally came up with a hand-written DSL parser, I accept this answer, since it **really** fits the requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

http://igagis.github.io/stob/ might be a good option as it is very simple. Although there is no plain C library, there is C++ library.